# Ubuntu server 18 setup as router

Tags: server, 18.04, virtualization, router

I want to makeover my current network and run my own Ubuntu router in a VM.

Currently i have 4 servers running and i want to take one or two down by using VM's.
My first goal is to setup a router server and bypass my providers router.

Can someone explain the basics for achieving this?

Thx!